# Что станет с сайтом, если htaccess будет большого размера?

Tags: .htaccess

Хочу написать вот так в htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule red f2.php?fa=5
RewriteRule blue f2.php?fa=6
RewriteRule white f2.php?fa=2
...
```

и т.д. примерно 500 штук.
Скажите, как это повлияет на сам сайт? Скорость не затормозится или нет? Вообще чем это грозит? СпасибО!

Comment: Читайте [сюда](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) про флаг `last`

Comment: Апач считывает `.htaccess` однократно, компилирует регулярные выражения и держит их в памяти. Ваше придумка конечно неоптимальная, но не критически медленная.

Comment: @karmadro4, [When (not) to use .htaccess files](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/htaccess.html#when)

> The first of these is performance. When AllowOverride is set to allow the use of .htaccess files, Apache will look in every directory for .htaccess files. Thus, permitting .htaccess files causes a performance hit, whether or not you actually even use them! Also, **the .htaccess file is loaded every time a document is requested**

Comment: @qwerty17, я просто поправил @karmadro4 на счет однократной загрузки .htaccess.

По поводу выполнения 500 регулярок *на каждый запрос* особо добавить нечего:

 1. Да, с точки зрения архитектуры так делать ни в коем случае нельзя. Вариант @Construct намного правильнее.
 2. Насколько это критично для вашего проекта - не знаю. Для домашней страницы с 10 униками в день или какого-либо интернет-магазина может и не критично. Для highload это абсолютно недопустимо.

Comment: @qwerty17, вы сударь не исправим ))) Эти "красивые" ссылки, которые в адресной строке отображаются, вы сами формируете. Я вам уже полномасштабный пример давал, но вы никак в сам принцип не вникните.

Comment: Не могу разобраться)))) это точно)))

Comment: @Deonis, вот разбираюсь в вашем коде, но у вас же все выводится и делается в одном файле index.php. А у меня главный index.php там несколько ссылок - щелкаешь по одной и выводится результат спец.для этой ссылки в файле уже другом f1.php... там тоже несколько ссылок - щелкаешь и попадаешь в f2.php... такой вопрос-у вас все делается в одном файле.. а у меня в нескольких... как это реализовать средствами вашего кода))) большое спасибо)

Comment: @qwerty17, делаете редирект 

    header('Location: drugaja_stranichka.php');

Answer (score 2):

Пишите

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ f2.php?fa=$1 [QSA,L]
```

и будет счастье.

Comment: если я введу site/red то выведется site/f2.php?fa=5  ??? что-то не получается... и еще почему 2 раза f2.php.php ?

Comment: Нет, он перейдёт на `site/f2.php?fa=red`, может быть перестроить приём параметров под это? Ведь, согласитесь, одна строка удобней пятисот.
php.php исправил.